# Custom comparison for the enum class

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a data class `TestDataClass` that has a custom `equals()` method, in order to consider the given threshold while comparing the `Price` property that looks like:

```
    private val THRESHOLD: Double = 1e-7
    
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as TestDataClass

        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (kotlin.math.abs(price - other.price) > THRESHOLD) return false
        if (curr != other.curr) return false
        if (desc != other.desc) return false
        if (quantity != other.quantity) return false

        return true
      }
```

Then there is an enum class that builds its properties based on the objects of the `TestDataClass` as:

```
enum class TestDataClassColumns(private val expr: (TestDataClass) -> Any) {
  Price({ it.price }),
  Curr({ it.curr }),
  Description({ it.desc }),
  Quantity({ it.quantity });
}
```

Furthermore, I have a `checkData()` method in the enum class `TestDataClassColumns` that acts is used for the comparison and returns the properties that were not equal:

```
fun checkData(obj1: TestDataClass?, obj2: TestDataClass?): Boolean = expr(obj1) != expr(obj2)
```

Null check is there, just removed it from post to have more visibility.

So far, the `equals()` of `TestDataClass` works correct, however I have no idea, how to incorporate the `THRESHOLD` into the `checkData()` of `enum class TestDataClassColumns()`. Any ideas how to do it? The overall design should remain the same, meaning that the classes should be there. Here is the link to playground with some examples -  [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/pfcCoeLBH)

Comment: You will probably have to override the `checkData` method for `Price` specifically.

Comment: `Double` is not an appropriate way to represent a price or any other monetary value. Floating point is a binary fraction, which cannot represent many decimal fractions such as one tenth or one hundredth. You should be use a BigDecimal or an integral number of cents to represent price.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, what do you mean by overriding a method for the `Price` enum value specifically? How is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks for the hint. Will keep this in mind for the future implementations. Not able to update at this stage though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checkData` isn't comparing `TestDataClass`es directly, it's just running some function on each that returns an `Any`, and comparing those `Any`s - how would you apply a `Double` threshold there?

Seems like what you want is to take two `TestDataClass` instances and get them to compare *themselves* by one of their properties. That way they can handle each property appropriately, and if there is a threshold to consider it's an internal detail.

Probably the easiest way is to just create a price comparison function in your class, and make the `equals` function refer to it:

```
fun isSamePrice(other: TestDataClass) = kotlin.math.abs(price - other.price) <= THRESHOLD

override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    ...
    if (!isSamePrice(other)) return false
    ...
}
```

Then you can make your enum call that - instead of having a function that spits out values, which you then compare, you can have a function that uses two `TestDataClass` instances instead:

```
enum class TestDataClassColumns(private val compare: TestDataClass.(TestDataClass) -> Boolean) {
  Price({ isSamePrice(it) }),
  Curr({ curr == it.curr }),
  Description({ desc == it.desc }),
  Quantity({ quantity == it.quantity });

  fun checkData(obj1: TestDataClass?, obj2: TestDataClass?): Boolean =
    if (obj1 == null || obj2 == null) true else !obj1.compare(obj2)
}
```

All you need to do is initialise with a function that calls that comparison function on the class, and it's all handled internally - if the `TestDataClass` considers the prices equal, they are! And because it's internal, its `equals` function can call the same logic, which is important - keeps things consistent and all in the right place.

---

The downside is that all the others need a function that explicitly compares properties, which is nice and simple but there's the *possibility* someone won't wire up the correct property on one to the same on the other. You *could* create a comparison function for each property (`isSameQuantity` etc) so that *how* the comparison is made is always an internal detail, instead of making the enum decide for some of them.

You can also write the function call as a reference like this if you like:

```
enum class TestDataClassColumns(private val compare: TestDataClass.(TestDataClass) -> Boolean) {
  Price(TestDataClass::isSamePrice),
```

I used a lambda for consistency with the others, but if you did end up making a function for each, that might be neater!

---

Another option would be doing it your way, but instead of `price` being a `Double`, it's a custom type with its own `equals` function. That way you could init it with a double value, but when you compare it with another `MyPrice` by equality, it internally uses a threshold value. Basically you're getting around the fact that comparing `Double`s just does straight equality, using your own type lets you tweak that behaviour. But obviously everything else has to handle the fact it's not a `Double`, and that value needs to be accessed through a property, etc

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the `THRESHOLD` from `TestDataClassColumns`, you have to move it to the companion object of your `TestDataClass` and make it public.

Then you can alter your `TestDataClassColumns` as follows:

```
enum class TestDataClassColumns(
    private val expr: (TestDataClass) -> Any, 
    private val uneq: (TestDataClass, TestDataClass) -> Boolean = { x,y -> x != y }
) {
  Price({ it.price }, { x, y -> kotlin.math.abs(x.price - y.price) > TestDataClass.THRESHOLD }),
  Curr({ it.curr }),
  Description({ it.desc }),
  Quantity({ it.quantity });

  fun checkData(obj1: TestDataClass?, obj2: TestDataClass?): Boolean = if (obj1 == null || obj2 == null) true else uneq(expr(obj1), expr(obj2))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this will and does not work.

Comment: @smb Yes sorry, it was too late for me yesterday, so I forgot to also use the unequals-method in the comparison in `checkData`. So basically, this is the same solution as the one from @cactustictacs, but less generic and with a little less code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a wrapper for a `Double` and use that in the enum. Something like

```
class MyDouble(val double: Double) {
    private val THRESHOLD: Double = 1e-7
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as MyDouble

        if (kotlin.math.abs(double - other.double) > THRESHOLD) return false
        return true
    }
}
```

And then the enum will be like

```
enum class TestDataClassColumns(private val expr: (TestDataClass) -> Any) {
    Price({ MyDouble(it.price) }),
    Curr({ it.curr }),
    Description({ it.desc }),
    Quantity({ it.quantity });

    fun checkData(obj1: TestDataClass?, obj2: TestDataClass?): Boolean = if (obj1 == null || obj2 == null) true else expr(obj1) != expr(obj2)
}
```

`TestDataClass` can stay the same that way. This will work for your example. But I don't know if it will break other parts of your code